# OpenStack:What is the difference between using "CLI to the OpenStack APIs" and the separate APIs of the components?

Tags: cloud, openstack, virtualization, openstack-api

What is the difference between:

1. using "the Command-line interface to the OpenStack APIs" through the command "openstack"

and

2. using the separate APIs of the different components (for example using the command-line interface to the Neutron APIs directly)?

Advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, but what I have been observing recently is a community-wide effort to unify the syntax of the different OpenStack services (and hence the subtle differences between their APIs and CLIs (for instance the param `--key-name` in `nova` vs the param `--keypair` in `magnum`)).

Thus I would say, since there is an effort to make the `openstack` command the de-facto standard, that it has more advantages (provided the individual clients are discontinued in the future). However, it really comes down to your preferences or your daily needs.

I personally prefer using the `openstack` command since I find more intuitive to "find out" new subcommands I might not be aware of, specially when using the autocomplete:

```
openstack complete > /tmp/completion && . /tmp/completion
```

In addition, to find out the equivalents between the OpenStackClient (the `openstack` command) and the respecting CLIs, this [list](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/latest/cli/decoder.html) might be useful. It also shows which legacy commands have no equivalent in the `openstack` command

Comment: Thank you very much! @vabada